# Is lack of attribution not a valid reason to raise a moderator flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, attribution

I asked for a moderator intervention on the following question [Type casting in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48187567/8371915) after seeing ([now removed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48187567/2)) comment:

> I am new to pyspark and i found the above syntax in another question

Code is clearly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484961/8371915).

Flag has been rejected with following comment:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Have I done something wrong (misunderstood attribution rules), or was my flag not descriptive enough (I found the source later):

> "and i found the above syntax in another question" but lack of attribution

Comment: How descriptive was your flag?

Comment: @AndrewMyers Added to the question.

Comment: Looks like the mod expected you to just add the attribution yourself, rather than asking them to do something that you could have just done yourself.

Comment: Above asking the OP to attribute the source (which you already did), what action did you want a moderator to take?

Comment: @BilltheLizard You know, provide some authority.

Comment: I'm a moderator and I don't even know what "provide some authority" is supposed to mean. Check out my diamond!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I declined that flag, because this wasn't really a case of plagiarism that required deletion of the question. Your flag consisted of

> "and i found the above syntax in another question" but lack of attribution

with no indication of what was copied. I looked at the question and saw a single line of code there, something they were asking about.

I'm not even sure that the source of that code is the answer you link above. There are differences between the two. I don't see enough evidence to indicate this was copied from there, nor is this a case where they're trying to take credit for someone else's work.

There wasn't enough here to warrant deletion of the question.

Comment: So why didn't you use the, "[...] didn't find evidence to support [...]" flag reason, rather than the one that you did.  If you think that this isn't plagiarism, say that, rather than that flags shouldn't be cast for plagiarism.

Comment: @Servy - I possibly picked the wrong reason, but I didn't feel this warranted moderator deletion of the question. I debated using either, and I went with this one.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree it's not plagiarism, looking at the actual snippets, it's just that the reason you gave is effectively saying, "plagiarism isn't an issue that requires moderator attention", which isn't the message we want to send.

Comment: I would have picked the reason Servy cited, too. But, eh, the milk's already spilled.

Comment: Yet another reason I shouldn't handle flags before having my morning tea.